# Read line from file with padding in Fortran

Tags: fortran

If I have a text file where lines contains some non-blank characters followed by spaces, how do I read those lines into a character variable without excess spaces?

```
character (len=1000) :: text
open (unit=20,file="foo.txt",action="read")
read (20,"(a)") text
```

will read the first 1000 characters of a line into variable text, which will be padded with spaces at the end if there are fewer than 1000 characters in the line. But if the line length is 100 you have 900 extraneous spaces, and the program does not "know" how long the line read actually was.

Comment: Sorry, after your edit I don't really understand what you are after. What is your goal? You should probably show some example. "read those lines into a character variable without excess spaces" sounds like nonsense.

Comment: How can you read a line and know what the actual line is? Does it have 100 characters and a line break or 100 non-blank characters followed by 900 blanks followed by a line break? If you read into a len=1000 character variable you can't tell.

Comment: You can't and my answer offers some solution. However, I really do not understand what that has to do with "read those lines into a character variable without excess spaces" . Perhaps you want to rewrite your question to something more clear? Possibly with examples.

Comment: Don't you actually want to read it *with* those extra spaces? Or which spaces are extra for you, those in the file or those in the variable? Please be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran strings are blank-padded. There is simply no chance to distinguish any significant blank-padding in your strings with constant-length Fortran strings.

If every whitespace character is important, I suggest to treat the file as a stream-access file instead (formated or unformatted as needed), read individual characters to some array buffer and allocate a deferred-length string only after you know the length you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

```
character (len=1000) :: text
integer :: s, ios

open (unit=20,file="foo.txt",action="read")
read (20,"(a)", size=s, advance='no', iostat=ios) text
```

After that last line, `s` contains the number of characters read, including trailing spaces, which I think is what you wanted.

Notes:

With a `size` tag, you must also have an `advance` tag set to `'no'` otherwise you get a compilation error. Since the format is `"(a)"`, the whole line is read so the next `read` statement will advance to the next line despite the `'no'`. That's fine.

`ios` stores a negative integer when attempting to read past the end of the line. This will always happen if the line is shorter than length of `text`. That's fine.
When attempting to read past the end of the *file*, `ios` will store a *different* negative integer. What those two negative integers are is not set by the standard I think so you may have to experiment a bit. In my case, with the gfortran compiler, `ios` was -1 when attempting to read past the end of the file and -2 otherwise.

Comment: There are standard named constants in `iso_fortran_env`.